# Have view wrap content, but match parent if space is available

Tags: android, layout

I have two views within a `LinearLayout`, both of which should `wrap_content` such that they are minimally large enough to display their content. The `LinearLayout` view group should `wrap_content` of the two child groups such that it is just large enough to display the content of both child views.

But after this, if one of the two child views is larger, the other child view should expand to match parent to fill the remaining space available to it. The content of the two child views is dynamic and is unknown which will be larger at runtime.

The two child views are a `TextView` and a `Spinner`. The `Spinner` should fill any remaining space in the `LinearLayout` width. But if I change the `Spinner` `layout_width` to `match_parent` and the `TextView` is not large enough, the `Spinner` will truncate its contents.

Basically I need a way to choose the maximum width between `wrap_content` and `match_parent`.

This is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
        tools:text="Label" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- or android:layout_width="match_parent"? need max of both... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a trick you can use to accomplish this with `LinearLayout` and no extra views: use `wrap_content` on the parent LinearLayout and `match_parent` for *both* of the children. As long as the LinearLayout doesn't have *any* children with fixed sizes, this combination will make the overall parent as wide as its widest child.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        .../>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

(I've added a background color to the LinearLayout to make it easier to see how it's sizing itself.)

Comment: This does do the trick! Odd how this behavior is for `LinearLayout`, differing from `FrameLayout`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I ended up finding this out on my own through trial and error, but can confirm that does the trick. I banked my head against the wall with ConstraintLayouts but nothing ever worked right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that your `LinearLayout` width is `wrap_content`. It means children will never fill full width, only if content inside will change width.

Just change line inside `LinearLayout`. From:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

To

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Making this change will make the `LinearLayout` expand to fill its parent. The `LinearLayout` needs to wrap its children's content.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the layout weight `android:layout_weight`. here is a definition from SO: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996104/8738574`.
set the weight of the spinner to be bigger to what the textView is, and the width to 0 (zero).

TextView:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0px"
```

Spinner:

```
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_width="0px"
```

Comment: This won't work, as the `layout_weight` works in the direction the `LinearLayout` stacks its child views. In the case of my vertical `LinearLayout`, it would allow children to expand their **height** to fill remaining space. I need them to expand their **width**.

Comment: okay, so you need to determine which view is the bigger and set the other to it, try getting their width at run-time and check which one is bigger and set their widths

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do this in the layout directly, without requiring code to do it. The view sizes are only known after layout occurs, so this would require potentially multiple layouts to achieve programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** see my other answer for a better solution.

I wish there was a more elegant solution, but the way I've achieved this is by adding an additional hidden duplicate `Spinner` view used just for sizing the parent `LinearLayout` to achieve the max of either `wrap_content` or `match_parent`, depending on which is larger.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
        tools:text="Label" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- visible view width set to match_parent -->

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerHiddenSizer"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    <!-- invisible view width set to wrap_content -->
    <!-- also set height to 0dp so it takes up no vertical space -->
    <!-- in code, set this Spinner's adapter to the same as -->
    <!-- the visible spinner so that it's sized the same -->

</LinearLayout>
```

This way, if `wrap_content` would cause the `Spinner`'s width to be larger than `match_parent`, the hidden view will cause the `LinearLayout` to size to this larger size and the visible `match_parent` width will expand to this width.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Ben P's answer accomplishes this while still using a `LinearLayout`.

After further testing different solutions, turns out a better solution is to not use `LinearLayout` as the parent view group. For whatever reason, a `FrameLayout` provides the desired behavior of wrapping the child view's content, even when the child view is set to `match_parent`, such that the max of the two sizes is used. `LinearLayout` does not provide this same behavior.

But then the problem is how to get the two child views to stack vertically. This can be achieved in the `FrameLayout` with a combination of `layout_gravity` and a `Space` view. For some odd reason, at least in my use case of using this layout as an item in a `FlexboxLayout` parent, setting the `FrameLayout` height explicitly won't work to size its height. Using `wrap_content` with a `Space` view set to the required height does work.

This is a layout that works, without requiring any additional code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- setting FrameLayout layout_height doesn't work for some reason -->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
    tools:text="Label" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I believe you can get what you want by using a LinearLayout and without the extra `Space` view, though I can't say for sure that it will work in your FlexboxLayout use case. Check out my answer below and let me know.